# Deploy Spring Boot app to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: jar, war, spring-boot

What would be the best way to deploy Spring Boot project, preferable just jar, to AWS Beanstalk environment. Or should I just convert it to WAR and deploy it that way?

---

Solution:

Basically what I did was this:

1. Created new class to tell Spring Boot that my app is a web app and that I need to create all necessary configs:

   > ```
   > public class MyBootWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 
   >
   > @Override
   > protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) { return
   > ```
   >
   > application.sources(MyBootApp.class);
   >          }
   >       }

(2) inside .pom file changed packaging to war like this: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

That was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to deploy Spring Boot to Beanstalk is to use the [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) for converting your project to a WAR file. Then you just setup your Beanstalk application to use Tomcat and drag and drop the WAR file. AWS takes care of the rest.

**EDIT**: Based on what Maksim did

Step 1:

```
public class MyBootWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyBootApp.class);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Change your pom.xml use `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Comment: Basically what I did was this: 

(1) Created new class: 
public class MyBootWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) { return application.sources(MyBootApp.class);
    }
}

(2) inside .pom file changed packaging to war like this: <packaging>war</packaging>

That was it.

Comment: This is not true, see my comment below http://stackoverflow.com/a/41563745/157591

Comment: @PeterSzanto keep in mind this was written nearly 3 years ago in the early days of Spring Boot and Beanstalk. It may be possible to deploy it as a jar now.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily deploy Spring Boot applications as jar file using Elastic Beanstalk. You don't even need boxfuse as described in the official Spring Boot guide. It is as easy as

Download the EB CLI, then in your spring boot project folder run

```
eb init
```

for the platform select option 2) java

add to the newly created .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file this

```
deploy:
     artifact: target/spring-boot-aws-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

(change the jar name to a matching one)

then change your application to listen on port 5000 by adding this to your application.properties

```
server.port=5000
```

then do

```
# Prerequisite : generate deployment artifact
mvn clean install

# Create a load balancing, auto-scaling environment
eb create
```

The full details of the process are covered in my blog article :
https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/spring-boot-aws-elastic-beanstalk-example/

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know enough about Beanstalk to be sure, but it looks to me like the Java container only supports WARs. You can still make the WAR executable for local (and non-Beanstalk) use (e.g. like in the [gs guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)).

Comment: Hi @Dave Syer, aws and Elastic beanstalk does support Jar as well, see my below comment and my blog post about it.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Spring Boot project to AWS Beanstalk, preferably in a jar file:

1. from the maven pom.xml change packaging to 'jar'
2. from AWS Beanstalk --> create a new application
3. inside the application --> create a new Environment
4. from Selecting Environment Tier, choose --> Web Server Environment
5. after in the web configuration --> From "Platform" have to be selected "Java"  (Not Tomcat in this case, because will be provided a jar file which already includes embedded tomcat, the AWS Beanstalk provides us the hosting server where is  established the Linux OS, JVM, and the compatible application to run with whatever is needed to support our app. If we would have deployed war file then the tomcat had to be selected)
6. the Java platform support also 'jar' files to deploy (although is written .zip/.war)