# IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

Can't get my spring boot application running on AWS instance.It works fine on my machine but it looks like autowiring resolves correctly in one environment but not in another.Looks like I need to clean up configuration classes a bit.Any ideas here? Thanks much.

```
 **Main class:**

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
public class Data {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Data.class, args);

}
   }
```

**Configuration**:

```
     @EnableWebMvc
     @Configuration

    public class AquilaDataWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/charts/**").addResourceLocations(
            "file:///var/lib/aquila/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        // Need this so we can forward to index.html.
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }
}
```

---

Exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-07-09 19:30:55.773 ERROR 18723 [main] --- o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at
```

Comment: Are you deploying as a jar, it needs to be a war deployed into a managed tomcat instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646190/deploy-spring-boot-app-to-aws-beanstalk

Comment: This won't work as we are using the internal tomcat container which is jar-based.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `application.properties` (or `application.yml`), make sure that `spring.main.web-environment` isn't set to `false`. This should solve the missing servlet context problem.

Comment: Bingo.That was the issue. spring.main.web-environment was set to false.Just changing it to true resolved this problem.Thank you so much.I can sleep peacefully now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have other @Configuration in your package, which get selected by your @ComponentScan (DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration that appears in your exception is, most likely, imported by @EnableWebMvc somewhere in external @Configuration).

Possible solution is to use a filter in your component scan.

```
@ComponentScan( excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class) })
```

also if possible include `basePackages = { "org.yourpackage" }` in your `@ComponentScan`

If possible also try  to include for better performance

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

It tells Spring to use the container's default servlet for certain requests, like for static resources.

Comment: Can't use excludeFilters in main class since that will also exclude all other Configurations I want.

Comment: Any suggestions here? This exception is now killing me.

Comment: Same issue for me and I can't exclude configuration classes either. I'm relieved that I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Cloud

```
       <dependencies> 
    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 

    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
     <version>{spring-cloud-version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Spring Cloud AWS also provides dedicated Spring Boot support. Spring Cloud AWS can be configured using Spring Boot properties and will also automatically guess any sensible configuration based on the general setup.

Also here is an [example](http://mtdevuk.com/2015/02/10/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-to-amazon-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/) that uses Elastic Beanstalk to deploy on AWS.

There are two differences between the War variant and the Jar variant. The War variant doesn’t need an embedded tomcat because it will be deployed in a tomcat server so the pom.xml has the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency set to “provided”. The Jar variant has the scope tags removed to include this dependency in the jar.

```
org.springframework.boot    spring-boot-starter-tomcat  provided
```

The second difference is the ServletInitializer

```
  public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 
@Override   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootAwsApplication.class);     
} }
```

Now that you have this application created, we need to generate the war file for deployment onto Amazon AWS. Right click on the pom.xml and select Run As->Maven Install. This will run the build and create the war file in the target folder of your application.

Deploy your application using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

1) Login to Amazon AWS.
2) In the main control panel select Elastic Beanstalk under Deployment & Management.
3) Click on Create Application in the top right corner.
4) Enter the Application Name and click Next.
5) Environment Tier – Web Server
6) Predefined Configuration – Tomcat
7) Environment Type – Single instance
8) Click Next
9) Select Upload your own, click Browse and locate the war you created earlier.
10) When the application is uploaded you will see the next page where you select your URL.
11) Enter a name and click check availability to see if you can use it.
12) Click Next
13) We don’t need a RDB in this example so click next here.
14) In this next step you are defining the EC2 instance that will be created, if you are using a free trial then stick to the free t1.micro instance type.
15) EC2 Key Pair, can be left unselected. You won’t need it for now and most likely you won’t have one configured yet. This will be covered in a later post.
16) Click Next.
17) In Environment Tags click next again because we don’t care about this.
18) Review the configuration, and then click Launch.

Comment: Kindly let me know if neither spring cloud approach nor Elastic Beanstalk approach works

Comment: I don't think now this has got anything do with AWS.I am just trying to install this app on linux server there.Problem is with Configuration.I am sure.