# How to deploy Spring Boot app to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot app to AWS Beanstalk. Originally I had the app compile into a jar, so I had a main class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Locally, everything works fine.

I changed the app so that it creates a war file by adding `<packaging>war</packaging>` to my pom.xml. I also followed this post:
[Deploy Spring Boot app to AWS Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646190/deploy-spring-boot-app-to-aws-beanstalk) to create the initalizer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class MyBootWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyBootWebApp.class);
    }
}
```

Now when I deploy the app to Beanstalk it doesn't do anything, I get 404 error when I navigate to the root url. What else am I missing? I checked the server logs and there are no errors or failures, so I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: Please find my step by step guide for deployment in AWS Beanstalk (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-boot/6117/deploying-sample-application-using-spring-boot-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/21296/deploying-sample-application-using-spring-boot-in-jar-format-on-aws#t=201610280951313280846)

Comment: Also, I would have given the steps to deploy in JAR format as well. (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-boot/6117/deploying-sample-application-using-spring-boot-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/21296/deploying-sample-application-using-spring-boot-in-jar-format-on-aws#t=20161028095358683304)

Comment: Well, my issues is not the deployment process itself, but why rather, why is  it that the application doesn't seem to deploy? I can deploy the war file to my local Tomcat and everything works just fine. When I deploy the same war file to Beanstalk it doesn't do anything. What am I missing? I can post the pom file, but basically I do have <scope>provided</scope> for boot in there. Can anyone else comment, please?

Comment: Go to application.properties file and put the context path which will resolve your problem.  Yes you can post your pom.xml and project structure as well. Also, I recomend to go through/follow  the steps mentioned on my above comments.